# O ViewData["ErrorMessage"] não aparece na view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Olá, eu sou novo na linguagem c# e gostaria de saber o porque o meu ViewData["ErrorMessage"] não aparece na minha view.
Controller:

```
ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "O e-mail digitado já se encontra registrado em nossa base de dados.";
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
```

View:

```
 <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Visitante" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            @if (ViewData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
            {
                @ViewData["ErrorMessage"];
                <br />
            } 
            <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input asp-for="Nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input asp-for="Sobrenome" class="form-control" placeholder="Sobrenome" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Sobrenome" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%" value="Cadastre-se agora!" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Cadastre-se" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Veja que na minha view eu faço um `@if` para verificar se o meu `ViewData` é nulo, se não for quero que exiba a mensagem, mais pelo que eu vejo o `ViewData` não contem a frase que eu designei no controller.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você está utilizando o `RedirectToAction` o `ViewData` se perde, para isso você deve usar o `TempData`.

O `TempData` usa `Session` para gravar os dados, ele se perde apos a exibição.

O tempo de vida do `ViewData` é apenas entre o envio através da Controller e a exibição na View.

Veja mais nesse artigo = http://eduardopires.net.br/2013/06/asp-net-mvc-viewdata-viewbag-tempdata/

Comment: Só complementando, tem esse link em português explicando as diferenças entre viewData, tempData :)) http://www.macoratti.net/15/06/mvc_conc1.htm

Comment: Valeu, muito bom o artigo, vou dar uma olhada